# Reporting Services: Hide all but last cell within group

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, rdlc

I'm a long time Crystal Report user but have finally decided to ditch it for MS Reporting Services in VS2010.  So, humbly I present my question.

I have a report that groups an account into categories and then displays a running total in the last field of the table.  I only want the running total to be visible on the last row of the group.  How would I express that in the visibility function of the field within the row/group?  Or is there another way to do it.

What I have is this:

```
Title                   Amount   Sub Total
------------------------------------------
Group 1                  
    Child Item 1         100.00    100.00  
    Child Item 2         150.00    250.00  
    Child Item 3          25.00    275.00  
Group 2
    Child Item A          42.00     42.00  
    Child Item B          16.00     58.00  
    Child Item C          80.00    138.00
```

What I want is this:

```
Title                   Amount   Sub Total
------------------------------------------
Group 1                  
    Child Item 1         100.00      
    Child Item 2         150.00      
    Child Item 3          25.00    275.00  
Group 2
    Child Item A          42.00      
    Child Item B          16.00    
    Child Item C          80.00    138.00
```

BTW, The running total is calculated using the rdlc aggregate function RunningTotal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out.  To accomplish this I placed the following into the field visibility expression box to show a field on only the last row within a group.  By restricting the scope to the group it works like a charm.

```
=IIF(Count(Fields!Amount.Key,"GroupName") = RowNumber("GroupName"),False,True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If You Add the total in group footer also it will work.

In Footer it will display the subtotal.

Comment: Except that I don't want an additional line below the group.  I wanted it in the same table.  Space is at a premium in this report and the data shown is only an example.  Otherwise you are correct.